# Why is the output (True, 3) after running these codes?

Tags: python

I'm a newbie to python programming. Can someone help me with understanding what each of the following lines of codes do. I don't understand how (True, 3) is the output after I run it.

```
def do_Search(dlist, item):
    pos = 0
    found = False
    while pos < len(dlist) and not found:
        if dlist[pos] == item:
            found = True
        else:
            pos = pos + 1
    return found, pos
print (do_Search([11,23,58,31,56,77,43,12,65,19],31))
```

Comment: Which part do you have a question about?

Comment: It defines a function. Then it calls the function and prints the result.

Comment: You should consider reading python documentation about functions, while loop and condition if else etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first off you have 2 auxiliary variables:

- `pos`, which will return the position of the item parameter of the function,
- `found`, which will return whether or not the item was found.

Then, from line 4, while the current position(pos) is smaller than the length of the list(you're still within the bounds of the list), and you haven't found the item, you continue.

If you find the item `(dlist[pos] == item)`, you update found to `true`, so you jump out of the while loop and to the return.

So, you have a function which receives a ``` list`` , and a ``` number`, and searches for the item in the list, and returns whether or not it was found(found variable), and if it was found, at what position(pos).

Comment: @jalazbe you commented on the wrong post :)

Answer (score 0):

This function execute a search task in a list `dlist`.
the while function means that the algo will continue until `pos` is equal to the length of your list. To check on every elements of your list. the `and not found` condition check that the variable `found` is still `False`.

when the element of the list is the `item` to find, `found = True` to stop the `while` loop.
`else` the `pos` is incremented as `pos = pos + 1`

the function return the boolean `found` and the position of the result in your list.